# how create a post counter for joomla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

how can i create a counter for my joomla site to count up automatic when i post a picture or article or something else.
here is my web site `www.fotografy.ir` .

```
<ul id="counter">
        <li><jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom2" style="html" /></li>
        <li>1500</li>
        <li>00010</li>
</ul>
```

here i used a joomla visitor module in first `li` and that working good for me , but in secound `li` and third `li` i should count up manually and every time i want to post i should open `index.php` and change the `li` text.
how can i create a script to do it automatic ?

its what i doing now 
for example : 
post count : 1005 .
1.post a picture > 2.open index.php > 3.edit text 1005 to 1006 > 4.save !!!

Comment: No, you never would edit index.php to hard code something like that. Once your template is created you should never touch index.php. For this you should run a query that counts the posts. You should make a module that does that and then put that module in the bottom2 position. Also it does not make any sense and is likely completely wrong in terms of html validity to put modules inside of a list.  The whole point of a CMS is to use the database and other features to make it so you don't do things like this.

Comment: and u dont know how i can make that module ?

Comment: Of course I know how, but what I would suggest is that you do something like look at the other modules in the core and then make your own. They are very simple to make. You can look at the copyright one. and then instead of what is in there, change it to a query to get the data you want. If you get stuck then post another question, but you must try on your own first.

Comment: but i dont know javascript and php language ! my skills is jquery , css , joomla and html

Comment: just help a little then i can start , i dont know should start from where !!!

Comment: Just clone one of the existing modules and modify it. There are tons of tutorials out there on how to make modules in Joomla.  The purpose of SO is not to get someone to do it for you.